# 個人情報をアクセス制限をかけたWeb上で管理すると、どういうリスクがありますか？

Tags: security

最終的にやりたいこと
・(自分の)個人情報を後で参照しやすいよう(データベースのように)管理したい

対象
・メールアドレス
・パスワード
・API Secret Key など
※項目は色々あり

案
・サーバへインストールしたPHPとMySQLで作成
・PHPでIPアドレス制限をかける(あるいはメールアドレスによるログイン認証を導入。もしくはIPアドレス制限＋ログイン認証)
・URLは誰にも教えない

思い付いたリスク
・他のWebサイト経由で参照元のMySQLデータベースへ侵入されたら、データ流出

Q1.アップロード&ダウンロードについて
FileZillaを使用してSFTP接続しているのですが、データ流出する可能性はありますか？

Q2.通信について
httpでは、データ流出する可能性はありますか？
httpsだと、データ流出する可能性はない？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Q1.アップロード&ダウンロードについて
> FileZillaを使用してSFTP接続しているのですが、データ流出する可能性はありますか？

あるか無いかで言えば、あります。

> Q2.通信について
> httpでは、データ流出する可能性はありますか？
> httpsだと、データ流出する可能性はない？

あるか無いかで言えば、あります。

Webアプリケーションのよくあるリスクは、以下をどうぞ。

- [OWASP Top 10 - 2021](https://owasp.org/Top10/ja/)

Webアプリケーションに限りませんが、一般的な攻撃パターンは以下をどうぞ。

- [CAPEC List](https://capec.mitre.org/data/index.html)